# laravel slow to render pages issue

Tags: php, laravel

I'm booting up a development server for my laravel project with:

```
php artisan serve --port=3030
```

The issue is that the response time is way too long (~17 seconds). Chrome dev tools are saying the routing to the index method is the issue but, I'm only attempting to retrieve a basic view.

[image]

Does anyone have any advice? This is an issue on all my laravel projects on my work machine.

Appreciate any response,

Sam

Comment: Is it slow for the first time startup? After the page loads, have you tried to hit F5 and the load time is still the same?

Comment: @MiSAKACHi Yes, the load time is still delayed!

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to boot up the freshly downloaded laravel package? Or you are already trying to run an application of your own?

Comment: @MiSAKACHi Sorry for not being clear, I have several laravel projects installed on my machine already, it's just rendering the views from these projects which is the issue. The response time is too slow and I'm unsure where to look re troubleshooting.

Comment: No problem there mate. Have you tried to download a fresh laravel package? Try to deploy that on your test server and see if the problem exists.

Comment: @MiSAKACHi Resolved! Following your comment I installed a fresh installation and noticed a message from composer saying enabling xdebug has a major impact on runtime performance. Anyway, disabled this in my php.ini file and everything works smoothly again!

Comment: Glad that you were able to resolve your problem... Cheers and Happy Coding! :)